# C++: Showing output/contents of arrays? Code looks funky

Tags: c++

This code looks strange, and the question is confusing:

****Assume that the code below is executed as a part of a valid C++ program: 
Valid Program:**

```
char a[100], b[100]; 
cout << “We value your input:\n”; cin >> a >> b; 
cout << a << “+” << b << endl;
```

**C-strings input is as follows:  are weird in C++

Show the output of the code and the contents of the arrays a and b?****

What is this question asking, and how might I proceed in trying to answer it? It appears invalid and confusing to me.

Comment: If that is the full text of the question then it is not well worded at all. I would ask your teacher for clarification.

Comment: It will print `are + wierd` if you replace invalid string quotes `“”` with `""`

Comment: With a `char` array or a `std::string`, each `>>` inputs one word (as separated by whitespace).